# How to apply the same animation twice to the same object in PowerPoint 365?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using the newest version of PowerPoint (using my O365 subscription) and am attempting to apply a Font Color animation *twice* to the same text object which will trigger at different points. However, I'm not sure this is possible. Here's a simple example of what I'd like to be able to animate.

Say I have a 3-item bulleted list with only the first item in a "legible" font color (you can still *see* the other items, but not as well):

[image]

Then I animate on click so that the next bulleted item is "legible", with the first and third items muted:

[image]

Same for the last animation, where only the last bulleted item is shown in the darker color.

I can get the first animation to work, but when I need to re-apply a Font Color animation on the text object that's already been animated to show dark color, I can't figure out a way to apply that same animation, albeit with a different font color.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a couple of ways to do this using animation, but it'll be far simpler to create three slides, each with the same text box, with the appropriate line highlighted, and use transitions to adjust what it looks like when you move slide to slide.

Comment: Simple. I like it. Thank you sir!